# Blazor: How can i check if the Param for the Callback function does exsist?

Tags: blazor-server-side

Example:

```
/Parent

<SomeTemplate event="@ThisEvent"/>

@code{
private async Task ThisEvent()
{
}
```

```
/Child

@Code {
[Parameter]
public EventCallback event{ get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to "check" if "event" has been passed to the Child as parameter ?
I want to use this in the Child to decide "what" this implementation of this Template should show and what not

The only Solution i have is to pass additional bool values to do so, im looking for a away to avoid that

Comment: Can't you just check for null?

Comment: @maciek - you can't apply null checks to EventCallback instances. You need to check if a delegate has been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to check if a delegate has been assigned to the callback.  I've set up the check to throw a Debug break if nothing has been assigned.

Also note the `EditorRequired` setting on the parameter which will produce a warning in the editor if that's what you want.

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics;
<h3>CallbackComponent</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public EventCallback<int> MyEventCallback { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Debug.Assert(this.MyEventCallback.HasDelegate);
    }
    
    private async Task OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await this.MyEventCallback.InvokeAsync(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for whether a delegate has been assigned is what you are after:

```cs
public EventCallback MyEventCallback { get; set; }

public async Task MyHandler()
{
    if (MyEventCallback.HasDelegate) 
    {
        await MyEventCallback.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Polite] What is event?  If you mean `MyEventCallback`, you can't apply null checks to `EventCallback` instances.  You need to check if a delegate has been assigned.